# How to use confirmation link without a specific view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backend, rails-api

I'm creating a backend api with rails and am hosting it on heroku.
I have a mailer which sends a confirmation email with a link to new users. With postman I can copy that link and make a `POST` request and the email is confirmed as expected. If I now open that link in a browser however I get a `HTTP ERROR 404`. Is there a way I can make it work?

I would use this api later with a mobile app frontend build with flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake, In my case I needed to change

```
resources :users, only: :create do
    collection do
        post 'confirm'
        post 'login', to: 'authentication#login'
    end
end
```

to

```
resources :users, only: :create do
    collection do
        get 'confirm'
        post 'login', to: 'authentication#login'
    end
end
```